# What can I do for a stray cat having an eye infection

Tags: cats, medicines, strays, eye-disease

Last week I found a neighborhood stray cat (he often comes in my yard) is having an eye infection.  His right eye appears to be half closed and abnormal with white eye discharge.  His left eye looks fine.

I am willing to take him to the vet if I can, but it's difficult because he is not so friendly to human and not approachable.  Actually I've been trying to tame and touch him for a year without any success.

I've been observing him for these few days hoping it will be cured naturally, while I think I should do something reasonable.  What are the possible options?  I have some my antibiotics leftover (still in good condition); is it good idea to let him take small amount of it with some food?

Answer (score 2):

While it's a kind thought, I would definitely **avoid** medicating the stray cat yourself. If by chance the medicine you give him causes an allergic reaction or worse, he may run away and end up dying because nobody can catch him to save him.

If you have a small animal carrier, you could place some sort of treat/food inside the carrier to catch him, with a towel/sheet covering the holes/windows (this is so he cannot see you when you are walking up).

Whatever you put inside the carrier should not be metal or harmful in the event the cat begins violently banging around in the carrier because it is scared.

I would also call the Vet that you would intend to bring it to **first**, to see if they would accept the cat if its too wild to handle. They will also likely provide good tips on how you might catch the cat and what to do.